# Minimizing registers per thread + "maxregcount" effect

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

Profiling result of my program says maximum theoretical achieved occupancy is 50% and the limiter are registers. What are general instructions about minimizing number of registers in CUDA code? I see profiling results show number of registers are much more than number of 32 and 16 bit variables I have in my code (per thread)? What can be potentially the reason?

Plus, setting "maxregcount" to 32 (32 * 2048(max threads per SMX) = 65536(max registers per SMX), solves the occupancy limit issue but I don't get much of speed up. Does "maxregcount" try to optimize the code more, so it won't be wasteful in using registers? Or it simply chooses L1 cache or local memory for register spilling?

Comment: Is the number of regs lots more than the number of variables or just a little? You need some registers for storing function arguments, built-in variables like threadIdx and some just for computation.

Answer (score 3):

As per the presentation of nvidia given [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/register_spilling.pdf). If the source exceeds the register limit `Local Memory` is used. Its worth spending time studying this presentation as it describes various options to increase the performance. As Vasily Volkov says in [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf) presentation occupancy is one of the metrics not the only one.

Also notice,

32 (32 * 2048(max threads per SMX) = 65536(max registers per SMX) is somewhat wrong I feel.

32 * 1024 (registers per block) = 32768 < 65536 ( registers per block). You can still increase the number of registers per thread till 64.

Comment: It's possible to increase the number of registers to 64 per thread. But in case of registers>32, two similar blocks cannot occupy one SMX that can have up to 2048 threads (32*2048=65536 registers). This is why maximum theoretical occupancy gets limited.

Comment: Thanks for the links BTW. They're very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

maxrregcount does cause the compiler to rearrange its use of registers, but it's always trying to keep register count low. Where it can't stay below your imposed limit, it will simply spill it to L1, L2 and DRAM. When you have to go to DRAM to fetch your spilled local variables, it can crowd out your explicit memory fetches and/or cause your kernel to become "latency-bound"--that is, computation is held up while waiting for the data to come back.

You might have better luck choosing something between unlimited registers and 32. Often some spilling and less than perfect occupancy beats lots of spilling with 100% occupancy for the reasons given above.

As a side note, you can limit regs for a specific kernel (rather that the whole file), by using [**launch_bounds**](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#launch-bounds), which you can read about in the Programming Guide.